# How to edit an Embed in JDA

Tags: java, bots, discord, embed

So I was wondering if I send an Embed for something with my Bot, can I edit it with the Bot afterwards?
If that's possible, then show me how to do it please.

This is my Code that I`ve got so far, but idk how to edit that EmbedBuilder afterwards:

```java
public class Giveaway extends ListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
        if (event.getMessage().getContentDisplay().startsWith("+giveaway")) {
            if (event.getMessage().getContentDisplay().substring(10, 11) != null) {

                long msgid = event.getMessageIdLong();
                String count = event.getMessage().getContentDisplay().substring(10, 11);    

                EmbedBuilder eb = new EmbedBuilder();
                eb.setTitle("It's GIVEAWAY-TIME!");
eb.setDescription("Prize: " + "\n Winners: " + count);
                eb.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                event.getTextChannel().sendMessage(eb.build()).queue();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So to be clear, what I want to do is add a footer to the message afterwards and change the description in some cases.

I have tried some things but I've not come up with a solution yet.

Would be nice if you answer.

Kind regards,
lxxrxtz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep the embed builder and create a new embed:

```java
eb.setFooter(...);
MessageEmbed embed = eb.build();
```

Then all you have to do is call `message.editMessage(embed).queue()` with the message you want to edit. You can access the message from the callback in your `sendMessage`:

```java
channel.sendMessage(embed).queue(message -> {
  eb.setFooter(...);
  message.editMessage(eb.build()).queue();
});
```