# How do I make my Discord bot edit its message?

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I have 2 `Message`s (specifically 2 `EmbedBuilder`s), I want the bot to send the first `Message`, then edit it to the second `Message` on button click.

```java
EmbedBuilder one = new EmbedBuilder();
EmbedBuilder two = new EmbedBuilder();
one.setTitle("1");
two.setTitle("2");
```

The bot will `sendMessage(one.build()).queue()`, And then it'll add a button to the embed (In my case), If the user clicks that button, The embed would be edited to `two`.

I have read the documentation but I did not get much information, So I assume Stack Overflow will help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to edit an Embed in JDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62260961/how-to-edit-an-embed-in-jda)

Comment: It does not fully answer my question, And/Or Does not work very well for me.
Sorry, It does not answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by sending the message and adding a listener for the `ButtonClickEvent`.

1. Send a message with a button

```java
public void sendMenu(MessageChannel channel) {
  channel.sendMessage("Page 1")
    .setActionRow(Button.secondary("page:2", "Next")) // add a button with id "page:2" which we can use later
    .queue();
}
```

2. Listen for a button with that custom ID

```java
public class MyListener extends ListenerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void onButtonClick(ButtonClickEvent event) {
    if (event.getComponentId().equals("page:2")) {
      event.editMessage("Page 2")
        .setActionRow(Button.secondary("page:3", "Next")) // update button id
        .queue();
    }
  }
}
```

You should read this page for further details: [Interactions](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/Interactions)

Comment: Thank you, That helps alot <3