# How can I edit a message send by Discord bot (Myself) with Java?

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I see many discord bots send messages, then they edit the same message by a button or so, I was wondering how can I edit a message sent by my discord bot?

How i want it is the bot will send an embed, then upon a pressed button, the embed message will be edited to sth else.
Any help?
I use Java jda.

Comment: I think your question is answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62260961/how-to-edit-an-embed-in-jda

Answer (score 0):

maybe so:

```
public void onButtonInteraction(ButtonInteractionEvent event){

    if (event.getButton.getId.equals("example_id")) // getting the button
        {
        event.deferEdit.queue();  //acknowledging the interaction

        EmbedBuilder new_Embed = new EmbedBuilder()
               .setTitle("exampleTitle")
               .setDescription("exampleDescription");  //building the Embed

        event.getMessage.editMessageEmbed(new_Embed.build).queue(); // editing the message
    }
}
```